# How can i append two classes in JQuery

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, django-channels

I have implemented a chat box message (live chat) using django and now i want to add css, but i have problem on how to append multiple classes on messege sent. For example, i want to show other user messages float left and current user messages float right. But when i submit messages is displays only on float right, because i am only appending one class to messege sent. I think this is because i am only appending class="message-list me", when i change class="message-list" this display all message to the left. How do i float each message to left and right?

This is what i got:
haha should float to right (flex-start), while pepe should float to left (flex-end).

[image]

Alert(e.data)

[image]

I want something like this:

[image]

consumers.py

```
class ChatConsumer(AsyncConsumer):
    async def websocket_connect(self, event):
        print('connected', event)
    
        other_user = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['username']
        me         = self.scope['user']
        thread_obj = await self.get_thread(me, other_user)
        self.thread_obj = thread_obj
        chat_room = f"thread_{thread_obj.id}"
        self.chat_room = chat_room
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            chat_room,
            self.channel_name
        )

        await self.send({
            "type": "websocket.accept"
        })
    

async def websocket_receive(self, event):
    # when a message is recieved from the websocket
    print("receive", event)

    front_text = event.get('text', None)
    if front_text is not None:
        loaded_dict_data = json.loads(front_text)
        msg = loaded_dict_data.get('message')
        user = self.scope['user']
        username = 'default'
        if user.is_authenticated:
            username = user.username
        myResponse = {
            'message': msg,
            'username': username
        }
        await self.create_chat_message(user, msg)
        # broadcasts the message event to be sent, the group send layer
        # triggers the chat_message function for all of the group (chat_room)
        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
            self.chat_room,
            {
                "type": "chat_message",
                "text": json.dumps(myResponse)
            }
        )

# chat_method is a custom method name that we made
async def chat_message(self, event):
    #sends the actual message
    await self.send({
        "type": "websocket.send",
        "text": event['text']
    })

async def websocket_disconnect(self, event):
    # when the socket disconnects
    print('disconnected', event)

@database_sync_to_async
def get_thread(self, user, other_username):
    return Thread.objects.get_or_new(user, other_username)[0]

@database_sync_to_async
def create_chat_message(self, me, msg):
    thread_obj = self.thread_obj
    return ChatMessage.objects.create(thread=thread_obj, user=me, message=msg)
```

Template:

```
<div class="message-wrap" id='chat-items'>

  {% for chat in object.chatmessage_set.all %}
  <div class="message-list">
    {% if request.user != chat.user %}
    <div class="msg">
      <p>
      {{ chat.message }}
    </p>
    </div>
    <div class="time">{{ chat.timestamp }}</div>
    {% endif %}
  </div>

  <div class="message-list me">
    {% if request.user == chat.user %}
    <div class="msg">
        <p>
          {{ chat.message }}
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="time">{{ chat.timestamp }}</div>
    {% endif %}
  </div>
  {% endfor %}

</div>

<h3>Thread for {% if user != object.first %}{{ object.first }}{% else %}{{ object.second }}{% endif %}</h3>
<ul id='chat-items'>
{% for chat in object.chatmessage_set.all %}

<li>{{ chat.message }} via {{ chat.user }}</li>

{% endfor %}
</ul>

<form id='form' method='POST'> {% csrf_token %}
<input type="hidden" id="myUsername" value="{{ user.username }}" />
{{form.as_p }}
<input type='submit' class='btn btn-primary'/>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
.message-wrap .message-list {
align-self: flex-start; #float start
max-width: 70%;
}
.message-wrap .message-list.me {
align-self: flex-end; #float at the end
}
.message-wrap .message-list.me .msg {
background: #bde2f7;
color: #111;
}
.message-wrap .message-list .msg {
background: #fff;
box-shadow: 0 5px 15px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
padding: 10px 5px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
border-radius: 5px;
}
```

JQuery:

```
<!-- Channels Reconnecting Websocket -->
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/reconnecting-websocket/1.0.0/reconnecting-websocket.js'></script> 

<script>
// websocket scripts - client side*
var loc = window.location
var formData = $("#form")
var msgInput = $("#id_message")
var chatHolder = $('#chat-items')
var me = $('#myUsername').val()

var wsStart = 'ws://'
if (loc.protocol == 'https:') {
  wsStart = 'wss://'
}
var endpoint = wsStart + loc.host + loc.pathname 
var socket = new ReconnectingWebSocket(endpoint)

// below is the message I am receiving
socket.onmessage = function(e) {
  console.log("message", e)
  var chatDataMsg = JSON.parse(e.data)
  chatHolder.append("<div class='message-list me'>" + "<div class='msg'>" + "<p>" + chatDataMsg.message + "</p>" + "</div>" + "</div>")
}
// below is the message I am sending
socket.onopen = function(e) {
  console.log("open", e)
  formData.submit(function(event){
      event.preventDefault()
      var msgText = msgInput.val()
      //chatHolder.append("<li>" + msgText + " via " + me + "</li>")
      var finalData = {
      'message': msgText
      }
      socket.send(JSON.stringify(finalData))
      formData[0].reset()
  })
}
socket.onerror = function(e) {
  console.log("error", e)
}
socket.onclose = function(e) {
  console.log("close", e)
}
</script>
```

Comment: In your code in the back end, how are you determining which side it should be on?

Comment: With JQuery addClass https://api.jquery.com/addClass/ you should be able to add as many CSS classes to an element. Just have them separated by a space.

Comment: @Hawkins... I want the current user message float to right, while other user message float to left. According to my code all messages (current user and other user) are being float to the right, but when I refresh the page the messages are floated correctly, because it reads from css. I think it is because I am appending my message to only a class="message-list me" (me is the current user)

Comment: @casenosensitive... I have also tried that awhile and I got nothing, maybe I was doing it wrongly. I am not so much good in jquery, you can help me by coding jquery with my question.

Comment: what does `e.data` has in it ? can you add that as well in your question .does it have both message from `me` and the `other user` ?

Comment: @Swati... Yes e.data have both message from me and the other user. I have updated my question, including my full jquery code.

Comment: also can you show content of `e.data` ?

Comment: @Swati... Pardon, what content? You me I should print what I have in e.data?

Comment: yes do `alert(e.data)` and add that as well in your question . So, that i could understand how the message are differentiated between `me` and `other`

Comment: @Swati.. I have updated my question, i attached an image for alert(e.data). Please check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217435/discussion-between-swati-and-mrhize).

Answer (score 0):

This is how i got it working, by getting the value of logged user and other user.

```
socket.onmessage = function(e) { 
console.log("message", e) 
var chatDataMsg = JSON.parse(e.data) 
//here `me` = $('#myUsername').val() which you alraedy getting in code 
if(chatDataMsg.username == me ){ 
chatHolder.append("<div class='message-list me'>" +  <div class='msg'>" + "<p>" + chatDataMsg.message + "</p>" + "</div>" + "</div>") } 

else{ 
chatHolder.append("<div class='message-list '>" + "<div class='msg'>" + "<p>" + chatDataMsg.message + "</p>" + "</div>" + "</div>") 
} 
}
```