# How do i show timestamp when message is submitted in Django Channels

Tags: python, django, websocket, django-channels

I am able to implement chat message in Django using Channels, but when message is submitted the timestamp is not displayed, only the message text. How do i display both message and timestamp together so that user can identify at what time the message is being sent. I have asked a similar question yesterday, this is the link: [How can i append two classes in JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62784679/how-can-i-append-two-classes-in-jquery)

Comment: This seems horribly trivial. I don't see what the problem would be.

Comment: @gre_gor.. I was able to do it using jquery